# Mongo DB returns undefined values in an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, undefined

I have this code that takes the value of the number of documents on a given day of the week in MongoDB. And as a return request, the "qweek" array is filled.

```js
function dates(current) {
  var week = new Array();

  // Starting Monday not Sunday
  current.setDate((current.getDate() - current.getDay() + 1));

  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var dd = String(current.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(current.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = current.getFullYear();
    var day = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

    week.push(day);

    current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
  }

  return week;
}

// Initialize the App Client
const client = stitch.Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("app-id");

// Get a MongoDB Service Client
const mongodb = client.getServiceClient(
  stitch.RemoteMongoClient.factory,
  "mongodb-atlas"
);

//projection config
const options = { // Match the shape of RemoteFindOptions.
  limit: 1000, // Return only first ten results.
  projection: { // Return only the `title`, `releaseDate`, and
    day: 1, //   (implicitly) the `_id` fields.
  },
  sort: { // Sort by releaseDate descending (latest first).
    releaseDate: -1,
  },
}

// Get a reference to the travels database
const db = mongodb.db("travels");

function displayCountTravels() {
  var daysweek = dates(new Date());
  var qweek = new Array();

  for (var l = 0; l < daysweek.length; l++) {
    db.collection("details")
      .find({
        "day": daysweek[l]
      }, options)
      .toArray()
      .then(docs => {
        qweek.push(docs.length);
      });
  }

  console.log(qweek);
  console.log(qweek[1]);

  return qweek;
}
```

In this case, when I make a request in the array console. I get this return:

```
console.log(qweek);
```

```
Log output:[]
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 2
4: 0
5: 0
6: 0
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Return of command `console.log(week);`

[image: Return of command "console.log(week);"]

But when I try to get the value by the index. The array item is returned with undefined.

```
console.log(qweek[1]);
```

Log output:

```
undefined
```

Return of command  `console.log(week[1]);`

[image: Return of command "console.log(week[1]);"]

I would like to know why the value comes with `undefined`.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you could provide the output of your console logs in plain text, rather than as an image. Thanks!

Comment: Also, please update the question with full code to understand the scenario better, specifically where you `console` print the values. Most likely what is happening is: the `console.log` of `qweek` is inside the `then()` block and `console.log(qweek[1]);` is outside.

Comment: @finferflu ty for the advice ^^

Comment: @ambianBeing Thanks for the advice. I did what you asked. Yes, I tried to put qweek out of then. But the values did not return or returned equal to zero. I tried to put a variable in place and feed the array outside the then as well. Ex: then (docs =>
     var daycount = docs.length);
and outside then

qweek.push (daycount);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this is a case of `asynchronous` behavior in Javascript. On top of that `asynchronous` calls are made in a `for..loop`.

**Short explanation:** The mongo-db query calls are `async` in nature and the execution is not going to wait for it finish before reaching the `console.log(qweek)` which is outside the `then` block. As a result you'll be getting `qweek` as empty[] or `qweek[1]` as undefined.

Couple of ways solve this is `Serializing with promises and async/await` or using `Promise.all()`. Would suggest you to read upon them to understand more.

Using `async/await`: Syntax wise less verbose and easy to comprehend

```
async function displayCountTravels() {
  var daysweek = dates(new Date());
  var qweek = [];
  try {
    for (var l = 0; l < daysweek.length; l++) {
      /*wait for the promise to resolve before next iteration*/
      var docs = await db
        .collection("details")
        .find({ day: daysweek[l] }, options).toArray();

      qweek.push(docs.length);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  console.log(qweek);
  console.log(qweek[1]);

  return qweek;
}
```

Using `Promise.all(...)`:

```
function displayCountTravels() {
  var daysweek = dates(new Date());
  var promises = [];

  /*each mongo query is a promise, collect and return*/

  for (var l = 0; l < daysweek.length; l++) {
    promises.push(
      db.collection("details").find({ day: daysweek[l] }, options).toArray()
    );
  }

  return Promise.all(promises);
}

/*Calling fn, getting results in then since Promise.all() itself is promise*/
displayCountTravels()
  .then((results) => {
    /*using map to get lengths of the documents returned and put it in qweek*/
    var qweek = results.map((e) => e.length);
    console.log(qweek);
    console.log(qweek[1]);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

Comment: Thaank you so much for help. You're saving my day :D @ambianBeing hahaha. I am trying to implement both options. But in both I am getting the following error.
```dashboard.html: 110 Uncaught TypeError: db.collection (...). find (...). exec is not a function```. How can I solve the problem related to Exec ()? And what is it for? Sorry for many questions haha ': D.

Comment: @JoãoGabrielAraujo Sorry my bad. Habit of writing ..since I've use mongoose with mongodb and there `exec()` is used to get full fledged promise. And Though u were using the same. Clearly you are not, in native mongo with node the queries are promises( no need of `.exec()`). Yon can remove the `.exec()`. I've updated the answer. And you are most welcome. Let me know if this works.

Comment: OMG, OMG. The first solution WORKS!!!! Thank you sooo much. OMG. that's a man, that's a man!! HaHa. I just switch ```exec()``` to ```.toArray();```